# Using constructors vs setting functions

Tags: oop

Is it better to use constructors with parameters to initialize the members of a class or do that indirectly using setter functions? I did not get a clear answer on this question so far. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't get a clear answer? Where else did you ask the question?

Comment: While there is a minor smidgin of C++ specificity, I removed the C++ tag in favor of the more general "OOP" tag. I don't think there is a suitable answer anyway (so I voted Not Constructive), although there is lots of advice/advocates for either appropriate.

Comment: Define "better".   How would you like to measure it?  And from whose point of view?  That of the developer or the user of the class?  (Hint: You're better off taking the point of view of the user.  And you can find out what that is when you unit test your class.)

Comment: Sometimes constructor parameters are the only option, for instance, if a member is not default constructible, or a member that is a reference. Otherwise, it really depends on the use case. The goal should be that your object is left in a valid state upon construction. Setting optional parameters via setters is OK, although I personally prefer constructors with default parameters for these.

Comment: I'd recommend either multiple constructors, with appropriate defaults passed to this(), or the builder pattern.  I prefer both to leaving references at null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is almost certainly a matter of design choice or sometimes style. I would consider a number of things:

1. Would constructing an object without setting the member variables leave the class in an invalid state? If so, you'll need your constructor to take valid values for those members. Otherwise, you should be able to provide useful defaults.
2. Would setting individual members of variables violate a class invariant? If so, they should not have their own setters.
3. Is the user of this class likely to want to modify individual members? If so, then setters may be appropriate.
4. Does it make conceptual sense to be able to change individual members of an object? I would argue that it makes no sense to be able to change a `Person`'s date of birth. However, you could argue that changing a `Person`'s name does make sense. It depends. Do you consider a `Person` whose name has changed to be a different `Person` in your system?
5. Can you group setters together to be more useful? Instead of `Rectangle::setX(int)` and `Rectangle::setY(int)`, does `Rectangle::setPosition(int,int)` make more sense? Perhaps even `Rectangle::setPosition(Point)` is better.

In any case, a class whose full set of members are exposed through individual setters and getters is usually a code smell.

Answer (score 2):

The one thing you want to avoid is having an object that isn't complete. If you can supply sensible defaults for every parameter then it's OK to skip setting them in the constructor, otherwise you really should put them there.

Naturally there's no reason you can't do both.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Certainly use constructor parameters where the object doesn't make sense without a valid class member - for example, scoped smart pointers, or an ofstream's filename.

```
explicit ofstream ( const char * filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::out );
```

Use additional parameters sparingly, and provide default values wherever possible.

However, don't add so many constructor parameters that the order becomes impossible to remember, or if there's a chance of dangerous confusion, such as this.

```
Person(std::string firstname, std::string lastname, std::string title, std::string occupation,
  std::string address, std::string telephone, int age, std::string creditcard, time_t birthday)
```

Comment: Zero votes but accepted. That's always embarrassing...